# How to fetch button type from querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to this want to select following button type in the querySelectorAll

```
<button type="submit">Comment</button>
```

Also can i check type= submit and it contains "Comment" ?

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('button[type="submit"]')`

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps:

```
document.querySelectorAll("button[type=submit]");
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Along with this  can i check its "Comment" ??  Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes you can if there is one result of
document.querySelectorAll("button[type=submit]")

You can do like this:

if(document.querySelectorAll("button[type=submit]")[0].innerHTML == "Comment"){ return true; }

Give tick mark if resolved :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `button[type=submit]` will help you. Also you can access it's style and value.

**Check:**

```js
function myFunction() {
   
var y = document.querySelectorAll("button[type=submit]");
y[0].style.color = "blue";
  
  
var txt = y[0].textContent || y[0].innerText;
alert(txt);
  
  
}
```

```html
<button type="submit">Comment</button>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a class to your button and doing this:

```
var matches = document.querySelectorAll("button.comment");
console.log(matches);

<button type="submit" class="comment">Comment</button>
<button type="submit" class="comment">Comment</button>
```

This will return a list of buttons with the `comment` class.

https://jsfiddle.net/nso2bzm6/